# What does "stepped up" mean?

Tags: meaning

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury), Nick Easter asks Marlee about their attorney Rohr:

> Nick Easter: Where are we with Rohr?
>
> Marlee: He hasn't **stepped up** yet. He will.

What does "stepped up" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to (generally successfully) meet a challenge of some kind.